# Computing a limit using L'Hospital's rule

Tags: limits, solution-verification

I am trying to evaluate
$$ 
\lim\limits_{x \to 0} \frac{(e^x - 1)^2}{1 - \cos x}.
$$
This is of the form $\frac{0}{0}$, so I can use L'Hospital's rule to differentiate using the chain rule:
\begin{align*}
\lim\limits_{x \to 0} \frac{2(e^x - 1)e^x}{\sin x} = \lim\limits_{x \to 0} \frac{2e^{2x} - e^x}{\sin x}.
\end{align*}
This is another indetermiante form, and if I keep applying L'Hospital's rule, the expression will only become more complicated. I consider using Taylor series, but all that allow me to do is cancel out the $1$'s and then apply L'Hospital's rule.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: **Hint**: Use $$\frac {1-\cos x}2=\sin^2\left(\frac x 2\right).$$

Answer (score 2):

\begin{align}
 \lim_{x\to0}\frac{(e^x-1)^2}{1-\cos x} & = \lim_{x\to0}\frac{(e^x-1)^2}{(1-\cos x)}\frac{x^2}{x^2} \\
 & = \lim_{x\to0}\left(\frac{e^x-1}{x}\right)^2\left(\frac{\frac{x^2}{4}}{2\sin^2\frac x2}\right)\times4 \\
 & = 1\times\frac12\times4 \\
 & = 2 \\
\end{align}

Comment: I prefer this ☺️

Answer (score 1):

Use L'Hospital rule for one more time, it will not be complicated. Also, your intermediated calculation contains a mistake (or typo?)

$\lim_{x\to 0}\dfrac{(e^x-1)^2}{1-\cos x}$, after applying L'Hospital rule for once gives you $\lim_{x\to 0}\dfrac{2(e^x-1)e^x}{\sin x}=\lim_{x\to 0}\dfrac{2e^{2x}-2e^x}{\sin x}$, which is again produces indeterminate form. So, again applying L'Hospital rule, we get $\lim_{x\to 0}\dfrac{4e^{2x}-2e^x}{\cos x}=2.$